# get x & y & z position for CALayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer

I want to get x,y,z position of CAlayer can i get it directly or i should use transform matrix ?

i know how to set its value

```
[layer setValue:value forKeyPath:@"transform.translation.z"];
[layer setValue:value forKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
[layer setValue:value forKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
```

but i don't know how to get them back ?

if i should use transform matrix what are the equations ?

and how can i get its rotation angle ?

Comment: Since you're the one applying them, why don't you keep track of them as you apply them?

Comment: Why can't you move the layers with `layer.position` and `layer.zPosition`?